# Best way to handle multiple conditions for conditional compilation

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae

I have a template class that has a method where the template parameters dictate the inputs and outputs of that method like so:

```
template <typename In, typename Out>
class Foo
{
    Out fn(const In& in)
    {
        Out out;
        return out;
    }
}
```

So I tried this, but then (probably obvious) errors arise when trying to use `void` for either `In` or `Out`. So I tried to add multiple methods that are variations on this theme hoping that their substitutions would enable the relevant functions and disable the invalid ones:

```
template <std::enable_if_t<std::is_void<InputType>::value>* = nullptr>
OutputType fn()
{
    OutputType out;
    return out;
}

template <std::enable_if<(!std::is_void<OutputType>::value) && (!std::is_void<InputType>::value)>* = nullptr>
OutputType fn(InputType& t)
{
    OutputType out;
    return out;
}

template <std::enable_if<std::is_void<OutputType>::value>* = nullptr>
void fn(InputType& t)
{}
```

Which lands me back in "invalid reference to void" territory, or with colliding signatures.

How should I go about gracefully handling these conditions so that only one of the following signatures was created from the template:

```
/*In == void && Out != void*/
Out fn(/* no input here to keep compiler happy*/) { return Out; }

/*In != void && Out != void, standard case*/
Out fn(const In& in) { return Out; }

/*In != void && Out == void*/
void fn(const In& in) { /* No returns here to keep compiler happy*/; }
```

Comment: You can [make the variant with the multiple templated methods work](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/591e6dca35aa6e67). But I wouldn't recommend you to walk this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [partial specialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) to provide implementations of `Foo` for when either of `In` and `Out` are void, and [explicit specialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) for when both are void.

The syntax is as follows (note the angle brackets after `Foo` denoting this is a *specialisation* of the primary `Foo` class template)

```
template<typename Out>
struct Foo<void, Out>  // specialisation for only In = void
{ ... };

template<typename In>
struct Foo<In, void>   // specialisation for only Out = void
{ ... };

template<>
struct Foo<void, void> // specialisation for both In and Out = void
{ ... };
```

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>

// primary class template
template <typename In, typename Out>
struct Foo {
    Out fn(const In& in) { return Out{}; }
};

// partial specialisation for when In=void
template<typename Out>
struct Foo<void, Out> {
    Out fn() { return Out{}; }
};

// partial specialisation for when Out=void
template<typename In>
struct Foo<In, void> {
    void fn(const In& in) { }
};

// explicit specialisation for when both In=void and Out=void
template<>
struct Foo<void, void> {
    void fn() { }
};

int main() {
    Foo<int, double> f;
    f.fn(5);

    Foo<void, void> g;
    g.fn();

    Foo<void, int> h;
    h.fn();

    Foo<int, void> i;
    i.fn(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value and the input value are different problem and you can solve they independently.

First of all, I suggest you to switch the order of the template types: first `Out`, next `In`.

This is because if you transform `In` in a variadic list of input types

```
template <typename Out, typename ... Ins>
struct Foo { /* ... */ };
```

you automatically solve the `void` input type (you simply don't express it).

Not a great solution because can be difficult to use the input value; just to show you how to create a struct/method that works in all cases.

For the return `void` type, you can simply do

```
return (Out)someVal;
```

where `someVal` is of type `Out`, when `Out` isn't `void`, and of another type (by example: `int`) if `Out` is `void`.

So if you define a type traits `deVoid` as follows

```
template <typename T>
struct deVoid
 { using type = T; };

template <>
struct deVoid<void>
 { using type = int; }; // a fake not-void type

template <typename T>
using deVoid_t = typename deVoid<T>::type;
```

you can define the `out` variable as follows

```
  deVoid_t<Out> out {};
```

and `return` this way

```
  return (Out)out;
```

that works also when `Out` is `void`.

So you can write `Foo` as follows

```
template <typename Out, typename ... Ins>
struct Foo
 {
   Out fn (Ins const & ... ins)
    {
      deVoid_t<Out> out {};

      return (Out)out;
    }
 };
```

that works with zero input types (ex `void` input type) and with a `void` return type.

The following is a full working example

```
template <typename T>
struct deVoid
 { using type = T; };

template <>
struct deVoid<void>
 { using type = int; }; // a fake not-void type

template <typename T>
using deVoid_t = typename deVoid<T>::type;

template <typename Out, typename ... Ins>
struct Foo
 {
   Out fn (Ins const & ... ins)
    {
      deVoid_t<Out> out {};

      return (Out)out;
    }
 };

int main ()
 {
   Foo<int, int>         f; f.fn(42);
   Foo<void>             g; g.fn();
   Foo<int>              h; h.fn();
   Foo<void, int>        i; i.fn(42);
   Foo<void, int, long>  j; j.fn(42, 84L);
 }
```